# "Engine source code was not found" error in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, 3d, unreal-engine4

I'd wanted to create a C++ project in Unreal Engine 4 and this message appeared:

> Engine source code was not found. In order to use a C++ template, you
> must have engine source code in Engine/Source.

I think I've done all the possible things to solve the problem: I've reinstalled Unreal Engine, updated Visual Studio and even have installed Unreal Engine via source code from GitHub! I have no idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error. I solved the problem by renaming the file path to English.
(in my case, the Cyrillic alphabet is to blame)